# Prolog - questions related to graph traversal

Tags: prolog, logic, graph-theory, traversal

I'm fairly new to prolog and logic programming in general and took up this example to learn but I'm having a hard time with the solution. So, if someone can help me out or point me in the right direction, that would be really great.

The following is a list of predicates flight(city-a,city-b,airline,distance,time,cost) and country(city,state)

```
flight(london,dublin,aerlingus,500,45,150).
flight(rome,london,ba,1500,150,400).
flight(rome,paris,airfrance,1200,120,500). 
flight(paris,dublin,airfrance,600,60,200).
flight(berlin,moscow,lufthansa,3000,300,900).
flight(paris,amsterdam,airfrance,400,30,100).
flight(berlin,dublin,lufthansa,1200,120,900).
flight(london,newyork,ba,5000,700,1100).
flight(dublin,newyork,aerlingus,4500,360,800).
flight(dublin,cork,ryanair,300,50,50).
flight(dublin,rome,ryanair,2000,150,70).
flight(dublin,chicago,aerlingus,5500,480,890).
flight(amsterdam,hongkong,klm,7000,660,750).
flight(london,hongkong,ba,7500,700,1000).
flight(dublin,amsterdam,ryanair,1000,90,60).
flight(moscow,newyork,aerflot,9000,720,1000).
flight(moscow,hongkong,aerflot,5500,420,500).
flight(newyork,chicago,aa,3000,240,430).
flight(dublin,london,aerlingus,500,45,150).
flight(london,rome,ba,1500,150,400).
flight(paris,rome,airfrance,1200,120,500). 
flight(dublin,paris,airfrance,600,60,200).
flight(moscow,berlin,lufthansa,3000,300,900).
flight(amsterdam,paris,airfrance,400,30,100).
flight(dublin,berlin,lufthansa,1200,120,900).
flight(newyork,london,ba,5000,700,1100).
flight(newyork,dublin,aerlingus,4500,360,800).
flight(cork,dublin,ryanair,300,50,50).
flight(rome,dublin,ryanair,2000,150,70).
flight(chicago,dublin,aerlingus,5500,480,890).
flight(hongkong,amsterdam,klm,7000,660,750).
flight(hongkong,london,ba,7500,700,1000).
flight(amsterdam,dublin,ryanair,1000,90,60).
flight(newyork,moscow,aerflot,9000,720,1000).
flight(hongkong,moscow,aerflot,5500,420,500).
flight(chicago,newyork,aa,3000,240,430).
flight(dublin,sao_paulo,airfrance,10000,900,800).
flight(sao_paulo,newyork,airfrance,7000,840,650).
flight(rio,berlin,lufthansa,11000,1200,1100).

country(dublin,ireland).
country(cork,ireland).
country(london,uk).
country(rome,italy).
country(moscow,russia).
country(hongkong,china).
country(amsterdam,holland).
country(berlin,germany).
country(paris,france).
country(newyork,usa).
country(chicago,usa).
country(sao_paulo,brazil).
country(rio,brazil).
```

I need to design the following predicates -

1) trip(X,Y,T) where X and Y are two cities and T is the list of all cities connecting X and Y. eg. trip(rome,dublin,T) = [rome,london,dublin].

2) all_trip(X,Y,T) where X and Y are two cities and T is the list all possible solutions of predicate 1.

3) trip_dist(X,Y,[T,D]) where X and Y are two cities and W is a list [T|D] where the first element T is the trip from predicate 1 and D is the distance.

4) trip_cost(X,Y,[T,C]) same as predicate 3 but C is the total cost of the trip.

Comment: Please show your effort and what you have tried so that people can help.

Comment: If you search this site (*e.g.*, `[prolog] flights` or `[prolog] routes`), you'll find this kind of problem comes up frequently. You should be able to get some ideas to get started and be able to ask a more specific question. If you've already tried some things, then please show what you've tried and ask about where you are stuck.